# android FragmentActivity is invisible but onStop() is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

Does anyone have the problem of a `FragmentActivity`, when call `finish()` on itself, it only calls `onPause()` and doesn't call `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`. But the activity is invisible on the device?

I don't see any other error log.

According to the android activity life cycle, If the activity is invisible, then it should call `onstop()`. But it is not. It is happened on Android 5.0.

I found the cause, but i don't understand why it happened.

A extends FragmentActivity, it is defined launchmode: singleTask.

B extends Activity, it is defined  android:launchMode="singleInstance", android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" in Manifest.

C extends FragmentActivity, it is defined launchmode: singleTask,  android:excludeFromRecents="true", android:taskAffinity="com.xxx.xxxx.xxx" in Manifest.

D is a serviceConnector singleton instance. What handles the event from the binding service callback.

The scenario is:

```
Step1 : A calls B with startActivity(intent). 
Step2 : B calls serviceConnector to send event to the service process and finish itself. It has no UI. It is set as Theme.NoDisplay.
Step3 : Service callbacks init C if not exist yet and C handle service responses event. 
Step4 : In one case, C calls B with startActivity(intent)
Step5 : B calls serviceConnection to send event. No UI. C will onPause and when B finsih itself, C onResume()
Step6: Service callbacks and found C already exist, no create new one. C handle service respsonses.
Step7: user click button on C Fragement activity, C calls finish itself, But only C got onPause(). C couldn't be finish, no onStop(), no onDestroy() is called.
```

I don't understand C calls B, B finsih itself, C resume and C finish itself later has the issue.

Comment: are you calling the super methods in onPause() super.onPause()

Comment: Yes, super.onPause is called. I updated my question. I found the cause. But i don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `finish()` somewhere within `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()` is called directly, without going through `onPause()` and `onStart()` methods.

Comment: I updated the scenarios with more details and i found the cause. But i don't understand why. Would you please take a check. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> It only calls `onPause()` and doesn't call `onStop()` and `onDestroy()`

If from `Activity1` you launch `Activity2` with a background that has transparency, then `onPause()` of `Activity1` will be called, but `onStop()` will **not**.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But the finish activity itself is not transparency. It has windows and UI. I found the casue and updated the scenario. But i don't understand why would have issue. Would you please take a look. Thanks alot.